# How do I override clone block?

Tags: 7, views

I cloned the *Block property* view and renamed it *Block portfolio*.

When I change the content type, the *Block property* and *Block portfolio* still use the same content type.

> [image]

How do I override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're configuring the filter, at the top, select **For** `This block (override)` or `This Page (override)`

Example:

[image]

Comment: I think you should perform a rollback (to improve the readability of your answer ...).